# How to put functions from one object file to one special section and memory region for GCC linker?

Tags: function, gcc, linker, embedded, ld

How to put functions from one object file to one special section and memory region for GCC linker?
I am building one standalone application for Xilinx MPSoC A53 processor. GNU ld from Linaro 2.27 is used. Xilinx software is Xilinx SDK 2017.4. I plan to put most code into DDR and some critical functions from one file into on-chip memory.
I checked '4.6.4.5. Input Section Example' from [Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html). So I created the following linker script. The output section '.text_ocm' is added by me.

```
.text_ocm : {
    src/ocm_init.o(.text)
}  > psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0

.text : {
   KEEP (*(.vectors))
   *(.boot)
   *(.text)
   *(.text.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
   *(.plt)
   *(.gnu_warning)
   *(.gcc_execpt_table)
   *(.glue_7)
   *(.glue_7t)
   *(.ARM.extab)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0
```

But I got error message. It seems there are two 'ocm_init'. But there is only one definition for 'ocm_init' in file 'src/ocm_init.c' my source code.

```
'Invoking: ARM v8 gcc linker'
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -Wl,-T -Wl,../src/lscript.ld -L../../a53a0_ddrsr_wfi_bsp/psu_cortexa53_0/lib -o "a53a0_ddrsr_wfi_step4_from_ddr.elf"  ./src/ocm_init.o ./src/gic_setup.o ./src/helloworld.o ./src/platform.o ./src/timer.o   -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lmetal,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -Wl,--start-group,-lxilpm,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group
./src/ocm_init.o: In function `ocm_init':
C:\prj\mpsoc\v174\zcu102\a53a0_ddr\Debug/../src/ocm_init.c:1667: multiple definition of `ocm_init'
src/ocm_init.o:C:\prj\mpsoc\v174\zcu102\a53a0_ddr\Debug/../src/ocm_init.c:1667: first defined here
```

Comment: I assume that since you're explicitly calling out src/ocm_init.o(.text) to a special section, that you'll have to exclude that same file from the .text section *(.text), otherwise you're asking the linker to include it twice...

Comment: I tried the following two method to exclude ocm_init.o. But they both do not work. I got same error.
.text : {
 
   KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (src/ocm_init.o) .vectors))
   *(EXCLUDE_FILE (src/ocm_init.o) .text)
   *(EXCLUDE_FILE (src/ocm_init.o) .text.*)
   .........)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0

.text : { 
   KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*ocm_init.o) .vectors))
   *(EXCLUDE_FILE (*ocm_init.o) .text)
   *(EXCLUDE_FILE (*ocm_init.o) .text.*)
   ........ )
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0

Comment: As an alternative to telling the linker to include a whole object file in one section, you should also be able to just define a section and then go to the individual functions in that .c file, drown them in some non-standard gcc goo syntax (which I don't remember, lots of __attribute and __declspec no doubt) and let the linker take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker cares about the leading `./` in some ways when matching file names, so either write

```
.text_ocm : {
    *src/ocm_init.o(.text)
}  > psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0
```

in your linker script, or reference the object file as `src/ocm_init.o` on your linker command line.

(It's not really intuitive why this omission causes multiple definitions, but I could reproduce your problem, and the change fixes it.)